# What is the unitary subset of Lie algebra $su(2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, quaternions, unitary-matrices

Lie algebra $su(2)$ consists of the $2\times 2$ skew-hermitian complex matrices with addition and multiplication by real numbers as vector space operations and commutator as Lie bracket. The i-multiples of the Pauli matrices form a basis in $su(2)$ as a real vector space. The Pauli matrices are the following.

$$\begin{align}
  \sigma_1 = \sigma_\mathrm{x} &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0&1\\
      1&0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
  \sigma_2 = \sigma_\mathrm{y} &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0& -i \\
      i&0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
  \sigma_3 = \sigma_\mathrm{z} &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0\\
      0&-1
    \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align}$$

The i-multiple of each of the Pauli matrices (that is, $i\sigma_1,i\sigma_2$ and $i\sigma_3$) is both skew-hermitian and unitary, however, their real linear combinations are generally only skew-hermitian, but not necessarily unitary. As far as I know, $\mathrm{span}({I})\oplus su(2)$ is isomorphic with the algebra of quaternions (where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix), and the group formed by the unit quaternions is isomorphic to $SU(2)$. So, the imaginary unit quaternions should be the unit-norm linear combinations of the i-multiples of the Pauli matrices. By "unit-norm linear combination" I mean a linear combination whose squared coefficients sum to 1. Is it really true? Is the unitary subset of $su(2)$ exactly this? How can this subset be determined without using the Pauli-matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $\vec{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ with $u_*, v_*\in \Bbb{R}$.  Also let $\vec{\sigma} = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3)$.
Then
$$
\begin{align}
(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{\sigma})(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma}) &= \sum_{i, j=1}^3 u_i v_j \sigma_i \sigma_j\\
&=\sum_{i, j, k=1}^3 u_i v_j \sqrt{-1}\, \varepsilon_{ijk}\,\sigma_k +\sum_{i,j=1}^3 u_i v_j\delta_{ij}\mathbf{1}\\
&=\sqrt{-1}\sum_{k=1}^3\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^3 \varepsilon_{ijk} u_i v_j\right)\sigma_k + (\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})\,\mathbf{1}\\
&=\sqrt{-1}\,(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})\cdot\vec{\sigma} + (\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})\,\mathbf{1}
\end{align}
$$

In particular we get that $(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{\sigma})^2 = (\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u})\,\mathbf{1}$ and $(\sqrt{-1}\,\vec{u}\cdot\vec{\sigma})^2 = -(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u})\,\mathbf{1}$.

Now, if $X\in \mathfrak{su}(2)$ then $\operatorname{trace} X=0$ and $X^\dagger = -X$.  So $X$ is unitary if and only if
$$\mathbf{1} = X^\dagger X = -X^2$$
or equivalently iff $X^2 = -\mathbf{1}$.  Expanding $X=\sqrt{-1}\,\vec{u}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$ in a basis, we see from above that $X$ is unitary if and only if $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u} = 1$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, making $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ to an Eucludean space introducing the dot product as $a\cdot b:=-\frac{1}{2}(ab+ba)/\mathbf{1}$ (this has sense, since $ab+ba\in\mathrm{span}(\mathbf 1)$), the unitary matrices of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ form the unit sphere in this space.

Comment: @mma:  That's right.  This is all actually embedded in the Quaternions.  $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is the span of $i, j, k$, the norm for Quaternions is defined by $x\overline{x}$, the trace by $x+\overline{x}$, the unit sphere of the Quaternions is isomorphic to $SU(2)$ and is homeomorphic to $S^3$, with the multiplication inside the Quaternions corresponding to the multiplication of $SU(2)$.  And the sphere of the span of $i,j,k$ (which is what you're talking about) is homeomorphic to $S^2$.  The action of $S^3$ on $S^2$ by conjugation $ax\overline{a}$ gives the map $SU(2)\to SO(3)$.

Comment: As far as I see, the unit sphere of the Quaternions not only *isomorphic* to $SU(2)$, but it *is* $SU(2)$ (at least if we define quaternions as $\mathrm{span}(\mathbf 1)\oplus\mathfrak{su}(2)$). Isn't it?

Comment: @mma: If you consider the Quaterions a subalgebra of $M_2(\Bbb{C})$ then yes. Hamilton's original definition is abstract with $i, j, k$ and their algebraic properties.

Comment: Is it correct to say that  $\mathrm{span}(I)\oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$ is a *model* of the quaternion axioms? (like $\mathbb R^n$ of the vector space axioms), so  $SU(2)$ is the set of the unit quaternions in this model?

Comment: @mma:  I don't see a problem with your viewing this sub-algebra of $M_2(\Bbb{C})$ as *the* Quaternions :)  Note that you need to take $\mathbf{1}, -\sqrt{-1}\sigma_1, -\sqrt{-1}\sigma_2, -\sqrt{-1}\sigma_3$ as a basis matching $1, i, j, k$ to get matrix multiplication to match the Quaternion multiplication.